# Orthogonal complement of a set

Tags: products, orthogonal-matrices

Could someone help me woth finding the orthogonal complement to the set

\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&2\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}3&0&1\\1&2&1\end{bmatrix}

(https://ctrlv.cz/T3IC here how it looks cause I can't put the matrixes next to eachother)

when the dot product is defined as 
$$(A,B)=Tr(A^TB)$$

Comment: **HINT**: If you think of the space of $2\times 3$ matrices as just $\Bbb R^6$, you're doing the usual dot product on $\Bbb R^6$. Then can you do the problem?

Comment: Not really sure how to tie it up with the orthogonal complement.

Comment: How do you find the orthogonal complement of the span of the vectors $(1,0,1,0)$ and $(0,1,2,1)$ in $\Bbb R^4$? Think of this as a homogeneous system of  linear equations.

Comment: So my job is to find a matrix B that would be put into the equation for dot product and would give me zero with the 2 matrixes in the set?